# Nginx(reverse proxy) cant forward SSL certificate of https backend to clients

Tags: ssl, nginx

I have made reverse connection to one of web servers on which is SSL applied and the the content is in dir (http://webserver.com/directory) ,so i had to use rewrite rule and that works well.

The thing is that nginx can't pass SSL from backend webserver and i get error on silverlight application..

Could someone advise me on what to do ? Config is very basic as only rewrite is added additionally.

Looking forward for suggestions,ideas,answers.

Best regards.

Edit: pastebin.com/SnyHaUL4

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, you could say that "*it's not a bug, it's a feature*", one of the features of SSL that it prevents [Man in the middle attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack), if you want to use SSL then nginx it self should have an SSL key and allow https connection, otherwise the user will see the well known yellow warning page about untrusted SSL,

If you implement the SSL for nginx, then the connection would be like this

```
client -> nginx ssl -> nginx -> server ssl -> server
```

The connection will be encrypted and decrypted twice on the way to the server, the client wont see the server SSL and will only see the nginx SSL.

If you don't have or don't want to use SSL on your nginx, then you need to make the connection to it unsecured, then the warning won't appear and every thing would work fine.

Comment: Thank you for your response @Mohammad AbuShady,i appreciate your help.

Can you perhaps provide me with example of .conf file which is capable of your example above ? Best regrads.

Edit : I forgot to ask,what about Self Signed SSL ? It requires approval,will it require approval on nginx server? How can i do this?

Comment: self signed won't be much help, cause it probably would show the same error, to see what i mean try opening the website that's not working and check the net inspector, either firebug or one from chrome, my guess it would show an error in the inspector, try it and you might find what's the problem you're facing.

Comment: for this particular problem i have verisigned SSL.. My current setup looks like client->nginx(ssl)>web server(ssl) and i get some weird SSL error from silverlight app which is configured to work on defined subdomain and directory... I assume that there is some problem laying in transfer between nginx and web server.. I am not really sure what to do and what to check as i haven't developed that silverlight application.

Comment: Do you think that nginx header requests might have different format than regular browser request ? Any kind of advice or help generally is highly appreciated ! Thank you for your time :).

Comment: the best thing would be inspecting the http requests from ur browser, it would show u exactly where the error is coming from, did you try that ?

Comment: i am not really sure what to look for in there. I have used "live http headers" addon on firefox.. From what i see it can't locate the favicon.ico and that is pretty much it .. Hover the error persist on windows when i try to establish reverse connection to SLL web server.. Also there is nothing reported in error logs..

Comment: Is there any public link you can provide? or is it still local stuff you're working on, also please share the nginx config file, add them to your question

Comment: i am unable to provide public link unfortunately. I will post my config in a minut.

Comment: sorry have no idea how i could help with the current info you provided, if you find any thing new or I figure any thing out I'll tell you

Comment: But why NGINX cannot just get the traffic from 443 and forward it to backend? It doesn't mean MitM because no decoding (except headers part that afaik doesn't require decryption) is being made...

Comment: @Konstantin to do that you need do the SSL on nginx, but the question was saying that the ssl was on the backend, and he wanted to forward the encrypted connection through nginx.